# Nginx - Generic redirect all www to non-www

Tags: nginx, redirect

Is it possible to make a generic HTTP -> HTTPS and WWW -> non-WWW redirect in Nginx which impact all domains. Or do I need to set it up for every single domain?

I've made the HTTP->HTTPS as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use two server blocks for this:

```
server { # redirect http/https www.example.com to https://example.com
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     <path_to_ssl_cert_for_domain_www.example.com>;
    ssl_certificate_key <path_to_key_for_ssl_cert_above>;
    # other ssl parameters here if needed
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server { # redirect http://example.com to https://example.com
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server { # main site config
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    # rest of your configuration here
    ...
}
```

Usually paid SSL certificates already includes both domain name with www prefix and without it. If you're using Lets Encrypt service, you can generate certificate for both `example.com` and `www.example.com` by yourself.