# Nginx re-directions from "www" to "non www" and from "http" to "https"?

Tags: nginx, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I have my app hosted in the base URL: `https://myapp.com/`

Now I want to add re-directions from "www" to "non www" / "http" to "https", where:

```
https://myapp.com/
https://www.myapp.com/
http://myapp.com/
http://www.myapp.com/
```

Last 3 URLs should 301 redirect to the first one.

Right now second URL is not redirected and the last 2 are redirected using a 307 redirection instead of 301.

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;    

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/self-signed-fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/self-signed-privkey.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ ^/(api)/ { 
        proxy_pass http://myapp:3000;
    }
}
```

So how can I actually do this?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969930/nginx-generic-redirect-all-www-to-non-www/60970218#60970218) answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just add one more server block with `server_name www.myapp.com;`, and add redirect:

`return 301 https://myapp.com$request_uri;`

2. Edit main server block to `server_name myapp.com;`

Should be something like that:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;    

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.myapp.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/self-signed-fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/self-signed-privkey.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    return 301 https://myapp.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myapp.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/self-signed-fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/self-signed-privkey.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ ^/(api)/ { 
        proxy_pass http://myapp:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: will this fix the fact that at the moment "http" to "https" is using a 307 redirection instead of 301?

Comment: I think it should do the same.