# Redirect Apache2 convert for nginx conf

Tags: nginx

I am in the process of switching from Apache2 > Nginx

I need this rewrite working, what should I put in my nginx .conf?

This .htaccess file is in /folder1/ (example.com/folder1)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
        RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
> RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

These are for redirection from `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com` or `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. You would need to use two additional `server` blocks besides the main one. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969930/nginx-generic-redirect-all-www-to-non-www/60970218#60970218) answer and do the opposite (replace `example.com` with `www.example.com` and vise versa).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
> ```

These are for redirecting all requests that do not match physical files on the server to the `index.php` script. The nginx alternative is

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was actually in a sub folder called folder1 how would I adjust this for that folder to be redirected to example.com

Comment: I don't know how the other folders should be processed, what configuration you currently have, and therefore I don't know the optimal solution.