# How should I redirect from non-www to www when https?

Tags: nginx

I've read in Nginx docummentation that instead of using IFs, new server blocks should be made.

I have tried making another block listening to 443 ssl, just to set there redvi.eu (non www) and then redirect it accordingly. It fails because of duplication.

How is the correct way to redirect https non-www here?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.redvi.eu redvi.eu;
    return 301 https://www.redvi.eu$request_uri;
}

server {

  server_name www.redvi.eu;
  root /home/deploy/redvi/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name redvi_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.redvi.eu/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.redvi.eu/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: You'd need three server blocks to do it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60970218/7121513) is an example for redirecting www to non-www; you'd need to do the opposite thing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do I really need certificates definitions in the first block if the only thing I will do is to redirect?

Comment: Nginx will refuse to start if the server block listening on ssl-enabled port wouldn't have the certificate/key declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have to comment the difference between the accepted answer and my [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60970218/7121513). Of course you can use two server blocks with the additional string comparsion operation during the `NGX_HTTP_SERVER_REWRITE` request processing [phase](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases). Moreover, you can even use a single server block like the following one:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # ssl certificate/key/ciphers setup

    if ($https = "") {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    if ($http_host != www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    ... # rest of configuration here

}
```

Nevertheless my advice to use three server blocks was given intentionally because of the performance considerations. That's because internally nginx will build a hash table for each subdomain level to select the proper server block via hash table(s) lookup with a complexity not bigger than `O(x)` where `x` is a maximum number of subdomain components for a longest hosted server name (e.g. `3` for the `www.example.com`). This is the same algorithm that is used to evaluate a [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block with the `hostnames` keyword specified, and explanations about its performance was given by nginx lead developer Igor Sysoev [here](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,214693,214694). Configuring nginx, especially on a high loaded system, you should not try to shorten your config in cost of performance. Nginx configuration is (mostly) declarative, it isn't a script or program code, nginx isn't an optimizing compiler to process your configuration most optimal way. The **DRY** (don't repeat yourself) principles aren't applicable here even if you got such a temptation.

---

In some examples you can even see something like:

```
if ($http_host !~ ^www\.) {
    rewrite ^ https://www.$http_host$request_uri permanent;
}
```

This one is the worst in the performance terms because of an expensive PCRE library call being invoked (actually even two calls when a `rewrite` directive used in the above example instead of the `return 301 https://www.$http_host$request_uri;`).

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation. I understand now. I struggle getting different certificated for different domains and my application is not super high load. Sometimes I value something pragmatic for each stage, but I always appreciate the full and correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't want to use "IF", there's not much you can do.

I've been using it this way for many years and it works well.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/sites/example.com/public;

    if ($host != 'www.example.com') {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    # others....

}
```

Comment: I was convinced that you needed 3 blocks, but yes, that worked as a charm