# Nginx - generic https and non www redirect

Tags: http, nginx, https, nginx-config, server-name

I´ve read a lot of threads about how to redirect www to non-www and how to redirect http to https (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969930/nginx-generic-redirect-all-www-to-non-www))

But what I am really trying to achieve is, lets say, more generic way **how to handle this (to have https every time and to have non www url every time) for all domains processed by NGINX**.

Is there any way how to have some "wildcard" server (or servers) that will

- automatically redirect every traffic on port 80 (not depending on url) http to https *(and possibly stripping www to save one redirect in case thats http request with www.)*
- if host contains www., the redirect to host without www with be performed (even on https)

The only thing needed **to add some new domain** would be then to **create ssl server block** (without any redirects) **that just listens on 443, providing proper certificates** and stuff

I´ve tried some settings but I´ve failed every time on a fact there was a https listening server with specific domain- server_name- (to add a proper ssl certificate for this domain) that have overriden the "default" which was handling just stripping www. on https requests (which caused the ssl www. was not redirected until I´ve added that redirect, which is a thing I´d like to perform in generic way for all requests on top nginx level)

Comment: Redirecting `http` the way you want is relatively easy. The problem is redirecting `https://www...` to the non-www version, because you need to load the correct certificate first. The simplest solution is to create two ssl server blocks for each new domain.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for reaching me. Yea, thats the state I am currently in. But I was wondering if there is some way how to achieve this particular case youˇve mentioned in generic way as well